# Cambiar color del TextView, Smal text, en Android Studio Theme editor

Tags: android, android-studio

No aparece ninguna opción para cambiar el color del `TextView` `Small text`

Como puedo cambiar ese color mediante el editor de Temas de Android Studio ([Android Studio Theme editor](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/theme-editor.html)) ? 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: cual es el minsdk que usas en tu aplicación?

Comment: La `api 16` y la `targetSdkVersion` y `compileSdkVersion` es la `api 23`

Answer (score 3):

Lo que deseas realizar aplica para todo el tema, pero parece que por medio del [Android Studio Theme Editor](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/theme-editor.html#basics) al parecer no hay una forma de cambiar el color del texto de un `TextView` con apariencia `Small`, únicamente se puede cambiar :

`android:textColorPrimary` para el texto "Large"
y 
`android:textColorSecondary` para el texto "Medium":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te sugiero otra opción que sería usar la propiedad `android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"`  para definir su texto como "small" y usar la propiedad  `android:textColor` para definir el color:

```
  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myTextView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Big Text"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myTextView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myTextView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"/>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sí. Justamente utilizo la propiedad `android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" ` y por eso quería cambiar el color del tema. Y mediante código no es posible cambiar esa propiedad del tema? Lo digo por evitar tener que definir la propiedad `TextColor`por cada `TextView` de tipo small que tenga la aplicación.